# Sending/receiving UDP packets on thousands of port numbers

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, asynchronous, udp

I have a set of requirements for a client/server application as listed below:

1) Program sends a *statuscheck* message to a host which is listening on a predefined UDP port. This message is sent on a source port number given by the OS.

2) The program needs to listen on the source port number initiated in step 1 to receive the response from the remote host. The program therefore must listen on thousands of port at the same time.

3) This process needs to be done for **thousands of hosts** per minute

Below I've created a sample example that sends a large number of requests to an Echo Server to mimic this behaviour. The problem that I'm facing is that although I close each socket after receiving data from the remote host, after about 16,000 requests an exception is thrown saying system lacked sufficient buffer space or queue was full.

What would be a way to achieve such requirements?

```
public void SendChecks()
        {
            IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("1.1.1.1"), 7);
            for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++)
            {

                Socket _UdpSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                stateobject so = new stateobject(_UdpSocket);

                IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                EndPoint tempRemoteEP = (EndPoint)sender;

                _UdpSocket.Bind(tempRemoteEP);

                string welcome = "Hello";
                byte[] data = new byte[5];
                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);

                _UdpSocket.BeginSendTo(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, ip, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), _UdpSocket);

                //Start listening to the message send by the user
                EndPoint newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

                _UdpSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(so.buffer, 0, so.buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, new AsyncCallback(DoReceiveFrom), so);

            }
        }

        private void DoReceiveFrom(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                stateobject so = (stateobject)ar.AsyncState;

                Socket s = so.sock;

                // Creates a temporary EndPoint to pass to EndReceiveFrom.
                IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                EndPoint tempRemoteEP = (EndPoint)sender;

                int read = s.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref tempRemoteEP);

                so.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(so.buffer, 0, read))
                //All the data has been read, so displays it to the console. 
                string strContent;
                strContent = so.sb.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Read {0} byte from socket" +"data = {1} ", strContent.Length, strContent));

                s.Close();
                s.Dispose();                    
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {                
               Console.WriteLine(ex);  
            }
        }

        private void OnSend(IAsyncResult ira)
        {
            Socket s = (Socket)ira.AsyncState;
            Console.WriteLine("Sent Data To Sever on port {0}",((IPEndPoint)s.LocalEndPoint).Port);

            s.EndSend(ira);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to send off 200,000 requests as fast as .NET will let you, and trying to listen to 200,000 responses simultaneously. I doubt the OS can handle this?

Comment: What would you suggest that I do given the requirements?

Comment: How long does it take before the 16,000 requests are made and the exception happens? I would think .NET could queue them up faster than the network can send them, and if that's happening, you're going to run out of a resource one way or another.

Comment: If you have an estimate on the kind of load you're expecting, throttle that test program above to achieve that rate, instead of doing as many as possible in as short amount of time as possible.

Comment: It takes close to 13 seconds before the exception is raised. The question is why is it running out of resources when there are still more ports available? There is more than enough ram on the system when the exception happens.

Comment: There's probably something in the TCP/IP stack, like an array of listening ports, and that array might be limited in its size. I'm not sure if that's the case here, but it's an example of a resource that might cause something like this... Anyway, good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to go in terms of performance and simplicity would be to simply use a single port number anywhere between:

```
1025 - 65553
```

Then when listening for thousands of messages from other peers they also send to a predefined known port number and you can process them asynchronously.

To listen to a known port number, in this case 60000:

```
 mySocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 60000));
```

Also do not close the socket after each operation! Keep it open and re-use it.

Properly written it would be walk in the park for .Net and the OS to handle your requirements.

Comment: Yes this would be an alternative to go. I can send thousands of requests on one socket and listen at the same time. But given the requirements of the problem I was hoping to come up with a solution for my problem

Comment: What system on earth would require you use different port numbers for each send?

Comment: Legacy systems tend to have specific requirements.

Comment: Looking at you question my answer would fit your requirements - just instead of relying to send on a port given by the OS send on a port given by you! Remote peers won't mind! If you really wanted to use random ports you can still use the same socket and use pinvoke on the Winsock socket to spoof the source port.